# How to get the sum of values in array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array with elements like a = [5,6,8,9,2,6,8]. So when I do the first iteration I skip the first index and then add the remaining elements in the array and if I do the second iteration I skip the second element and then add the remaining elements. ex: for the second iteration I skip the second element and then add the remaining elements as 5 + 8 + 9 + 2 + 6 + 8 = 38 like this I want to add the elements and find the highest sum of the elements and minimum sum of the elements. How to do that in swift?

Comment: `find the highest sum of the elements and minimum sum of the elements` — just drop `min` and `max` element of the list, and do the sum of the rest. It would be just 2 iterations and 2 summations, instead of `n` of them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```swift
let array: [Int] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var min: Int!
var max: Int!

for (index, _) in array.enumerated() {
    var auxArray = array
    auxArray.remove(at: index)
    let sum = auxArray.reduce(0, +)

    if min == nil || max == nil {
        min = sum
        max = sum
    } else if sum < min {
        min = sum
    } else if sum > max {
        max = sum
    }
}

print("MIN: \(min!), MAX: \(max!)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with one iteration

```
let a = [5,6,8,9,2,6,8]

var sum = 0
var smallestNumber = a[0]
var largestNumber = a[0]

for number in a {
    sum += number
    if number < smallestNumber {
        smallestNumber = number
    }
    if number > largestNumber {
        largestNumber = number
    }
}

let smallestSum = sum - largestNumber
let largestSum = sum - smallestNumber
```

Comment: I would just use `max(largestNumber, number)` and `min(smallestNumber, number)` instead of a condition

Comment: or maybe something like `var max = Int.min`
    `var min = Int.max`
    `let sum = values.reduce(0) {`
        `max = Swift.max(max, $1)`
        `min = Swift.min(min, $1)`
        `return $0 + $1`
    `}`
    `let maxSum = sum - min`  // 42
    `let minSum = sum - max`  // 35

Comment: yeah, that's very `swifty` 